# How do I join two tables while keeping their column names?

Tags: sql-server

I have two queries that return the mean age of customers and I am trying to combine their columns into one table, but the problem is that when I join them together with UNION it only returns one column from the first query.

```
SELECT AVG(C.income) AS "<50"
FROM Customer C
WHERE DATEDIFF(YEAR, C.birthDate, GETDATE()) < 50
UNION
SELECT AVG(C1.income) AS ">50"
FROM Customer C1
WHERE DATEDIFF(YEAR, C1.birthDate, GETDATE()) > 50
```

This returns only one column with all the data under it

<50

But I want this where I have both the columns from the two queries

<50 | > 50

Comment: I'm confused. Do you want one column in the result, or two? If you want two, what should be in each column, and why are you trying to use `UNION` to get it?

Comment: @BeginnerC, I think you are after an `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`

Comment: You are going to miss everyone that is 50. Put a >= or <= in there somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is *conditional aggregation*:

```
SELECT AVG(CASE 
             WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, C.birthDate, GETDATE()) < 50 THEN C.income
           END) AS "<50",
       AVG(CASE 
             WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, C.birthDate, GETDATE()) > 50 THEN C.income
           END) AS ">50"
FROM Customer C
```

This will return a single row with two columns: one for `<50` and another one for `>50` customers.

**Note:** `ELSE` is omitted from `CASE` expressions. If the `WHEN` predicate evaluates to false, then `CASE` returns `NULL` and thus the corresponding row  does not participate in `AVG` calculation (credit goes to @Samrat Alamgir).

Comment: I think this will not produce the correct result. For example, if we have 3 customers where 2 customers has age > 50 and incomes are 200 and 100 and the other one's age is < 50 and income is 80.
The above query will show the avg value for ">50" is **(300/3) = 100**, whereas the actual result should be **(300/2) = 150**

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will produce the output what is you wanted:

```
SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM
(  
   SELECT AVG(C.income) AS "<50"
   FROM Customer C
   WHERE DATEDIFF(YEAR, C.birthDate, GETDATE()) < 50
) AS a,
(
   SELECT AVG(C1.income) AS ">50"
   FROM Customer C1
   WHERE DATEDIFF(YEAR, C1.birthDate, GETDATE()) > 50
) AS b
```

Comment: @BeginnerC: It seems you are ignoring the customers with ages 50. I don't know this intentional or not.